# HTTPException on secured Pages after migrate to OWIN from FormsAuthentication with URLRouting - no Redirect to LoginPath

Tags: asp.net, authentication, webforms, url-routing, owin

I'm developing an asp.net multi tenant webforms application with URLRouting.

With formsAuthentication all works perfect.

When i switch to OWIN Cookie Authentication and request a secured Page i get the following error, but it should redirect to the Login Page.

> [HttpException (0x80004005): An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this request. You might not have permission to view the requested resources.]
>
> System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.PostResolveRequestCache(HttpContextBase context) +9727854
>   System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.OnApplicationPostResolveRequestCache(Object sender, EventArgs e) +82
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +136
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69

Route Definition:

```
//Default Organisation Route
routes.MapPageRoute("",
            "de/{organisation}",
            "~/public/default.aspx",
            true,
            null,
            new RouteValueDictionary { { "organisation", organisationConstraint } });


routes.MapPageRoute("",
                "de/{organisation}/profile",
                "~/secure/profile.aspx",
                true,
                null,
                new RouteValueDictionary { { "organisation", organisationConstraint } });
```

web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.0" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.0" />
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
    <authentication mode="None"></authentication>
    <sessionState mode="Off"></sessionState>
</system.web>

<location path="de">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<location path="public">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Startup Class:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/public/login.aspx")
        });
```

I have to implement facebook authentication, but i'm not able to handle it with default CookieAuthentication.

How can i use OWIN with my URL Structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found my Solution here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347546.aspx

Maybe there is a bug in the PageRouteHandler if you use MapPageRoute, because of the nested URL Structure:

> de/{organisation} --> is allowed
>
> de/{organisation}/profile --> not allowed

If you write your own RouteHandler and use UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal all works as expected.

```
routes.Add("", new Route("de/{organisation}/profile",
                                        null,
                                        new RouteValueDictionary { { "organisation", organisationConstraint } },
                                        new WebFormRouteHandler("~/secure/profile.aspx", true)));

public class WebFormRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    public WebFormRouteHandler(string virtualPath)
        : this(virtualPath, true)
    {
    }

    public WebFormRouteHandler(string virtualPath, bool checkPhysicalUrlAccess)
    {
        this.VirtualPath = virtualPath;
        this.CheckPhysicalUrlAccess = checkPhysicalUrlAccess;
    }

    public string VirtualPath { get; private set; }

    public bool CheckPhysicalUrlAccess { get; set; }

    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        if (this.CheckPhysicalUrlAccess && !UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal(this.VirtualPath, requestContext.HttpContext.User, requestContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod))
        {
            requestContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            requestContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
        }

        var display = BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(this.VirtualPath, typeof(Page)) as IHttpHandler;

        return display;
    }
}
```